# How do I remove blank columns in PowerBi made columns?

Tags: powerbi

I made some columns in the powerbi editor, DAX I believe, but I can not find a place to remove empty spaces.

I tried to search through column tools but I can not find out where to remove these empty columns in the powerbi editor.

Answer (score 0):

you can't really programmatically delete columns in Data View in Power BI (columns created by DAX), you can do that in Power Query, but not outside of it if those columns are not done in Power Query as well.

You can always manually right-click the column and delete it.

Alternatively, if you want to delete only white spaces from your rows while creating the column, you can use `TRIM(<text>)` function inside the column creation.